# Is there a way to pass a reactive variable in a method call in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i want it so that i can call a variable and manipulate it in the method like this,

```
<template>
<div>
<a @click=change(hair,'red')>Red</a>
<a @click=change(hair,'blue')>Blue</a>
<a @click=change(eyes,'yellow')>Yellow</a>
</div>
</template>


data() {
  return {
    eyes: '',
    hair: ''
  }
}

methods: {
   change(model, type){
     model = type
     ... someother actions
   }
}
```

when i call the change function it receives a model and a text and then i can manipulate it on the methods area

Comment: You mean you want to manipulate the state (data object)? And if so you need to do this[model] = type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the value of `@click=` in quotes for it to work.

```
<a @click="change(hair,'red')">Red</a>
```

Also, you are passing the **value** of `this.eyes` and `this.hair` in as function arguments when the link is clicked. This means when the `change` function runs, the `model` argument is set to an empty string.

What you want is an identifier so you know which to property to update. Just pass in a string for the data key you want to update:

```
<a @click="change('hair','red')">Red</a>
```

and your change method becomes:

```
  methods: {
    change(modelKey, type){
      console.log(modelKey)
      this[modelKey] = type
      console.log('hair: ', this.hair)
      console.log('eyes: ', this.eyes)
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you! thats why its returning an empty string it needs to have quotes

Answer (score 2):

```js
<template>
<div>
<a @click=change(hair,'red')>Red</a>
<a @click=change(hair,'blue')>Blue</a>
<a @click=change(eyes,'yellow')>Yellow</a>
</div>
</template>


data() {
  return {
    eyes: '',
    hair: ''
  }
}

methods: {
   change(model, type){
     // This line will update the state
     this[model] = type
   }
}
```